# Trying to detour IUnknown_AddRef_Proxy & IUnknown_Release_Proxy without success

Tags: c++, com, detours, dbghelp

For some reason, I cannot get the address of `IUnknown_AddRef_Proxy` and `IUnknown_Release_Proxy` using the `DetourFindFunction()` or locate it using `SymEnumSymbols()`.  I found another one in `rpcrt4`, but have determined that there is one in `combase` that is the one I'm looking for.

The two functions I've used can locate the one in `rpcrt4` but not in `combase`, and yet, when I get to the line in comip.h where it calls the respective functions, it does not call the one in `rpcrt4` but the one in `combase`.  This information must be available somewhere since the VS debugger shows it on the call stack. How do I get the address of the one in `combase`?

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 8.1 Pro.  Why does that matter @DavidElkind?

Comment: Because I don't seem to find combase.dll on my Windows 7 machine